# Most efficient way to search in a table

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite, database-performance

This is a general performance question, I have no error or something like this.

I am working on an app which uses a SQLite Database, and just want to know what is the best, fastest and most efficient way to query through a table to find a special value.

Example:

I have a table and I am searching for a special string.
I get all rows by:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

and then iterate through the cursor like

```
String searchedString = "THIS_IS_JUST_AN_EXAMPLE_PLEASE_IGNORE_TYPING_ERROR";
boolean success = false;
int count = cursor.getCount();

for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    String queryString = c.getString(1);
    if(queryString.equals(searchedString) {
        success=true;
        break;
    } else {
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Another possible way would be to use `query()`:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        TABLE_NAME, new String[] {STRING_COL},
        STRING_NAME + "=?",
        new String[] {"THIS_IS_JUST_AN_EXAMPLE_PLEASE_IGNORE_TYPING_ERROR"},
        null, null, null, null);
```

Is there a performance difference between these two methods?
A lot of tutorials out there are showing the iteration via loop, but the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) recommend to use the `query()` method.

Is the `query()` method the same as iterating through a loop?
How exactly does it work? I can't find in any API.

Comment: Both are same. No difference. In db.query(..) after getting cursor you will need to do the same loop to Cursor for getting data

Comment: That´s true, but isn´t it like the loop method´s cursor holds all information from all columns and the query only from one column? So for my understanding, the cursor from the query should hold less values and the looping should be more efficient?

Comment: Ya that's right. If you need only one column value then provide it's directly no need to get all columns this will take some time like `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Column1 FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);`

Comment: Thanks, I am just wondering if behind the scenes, the query goes through all columns, stops at the requested one, checks if the string is like the argument and passes it to the cursor -->then goes to the next row. If yes, then there could not be much difference between....

Comment: iteration via loop is the worst thing you can do, quote from wikipedia: `SQL queries allow the user to describe desired data, leaving the database management system (DBMS) to carry out planning, optimizing, and performing the physical operations necessary to produce that result as it chooses.` especially if you have db index for a field you are looking for the performance hit could be dramatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the search by hand requires more code (which increases the risk of errors).

The DB probably executes a similar loop, but doing the search in the DB does not require all of the data be moved from the DB to your application.

If there is not much data, there will not be any noticeable performance difference between the two algorithms. However, when the amount of data becomes larger, you can speed up the SQL search by simply creating an index.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can spot is the WHERE part, which lacks in the first algorithm.
The first algorithm will benefit a lot, if you add a WHERE clause to the query.   And then become identical to the second algorithm, in terms of performances.

Something like

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE STRING_COL = ?", new String[]{"THIS_IS_JUST_AN_EXAMPLE_PLEASE_IGNORE_TYPING_ERROR"});
```

As it is right now, the first algorithm is slower.

As noted bt @CL, both the algorithms can be drammatically improved by indexing the WHERE column.